# Период удержания onLongClickListener

Tags: android

Никак не могу определить период удержания, после которого срабатывает слушатель `onLongClickListener`, 1000 миллисекунд долго, 500 — тоже что-то не то (как минимум, кажется)... Через сколько все-таки срабатывает слушатель?

Comment: Трудно представить, зачем бы вам вообще могло понадобиться это. Проясните, если не сложно.

Comment: На разных дивайсах запросто может быть по-разному.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Зависит от настроек девайса. Дефолтное значение в сдк 500, но производитель может его менять.
Кусок из исходников сдк

```
private static final int DEFAULT_LONG_PRESS_TIMEOUT = 500;
public static int getLongPressTimeout() {
    return AppGlobals.getIntCoreSetting(Settings.Secure.LONG_PRESS_TIMEOUT,
            DEFAULT_LONG_PRESS_TIMEOUT);
}
```